# Adding custom CSS file to Dash in Julia

Tags: css, julia, plotly-dash

For Python there is an option to add custom CSS to a Dash app. The method seems quite straightforward, it says

> Just create a folder named assets in the root of your app directory
> and include your CSS and JavaScript files in that folder. Dash will
> automatically serve all of the files that are included in this folder.
> By default the url to request the assets will be /assets but you can
> customize this with the assets_url_path argument to dash.Dash

source: https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources

However when I try to do so in Julia, nothing happens.

Is this feature a thing in Julia? If not, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Found a hack, have no idea if this is the correct way though...

Essentially tried to find the inputs to `app = dash()` by going `methods(dash)`

```
julia> methods(dash)
# 1 method for generic function "dash":
[1] dash(; external_stylesheets, external_scripts, url_base_pathname, requests_pathname_prefix, routes_pathname_prefix, assets_folder, assets_url_path, assets_ignore, serve_locally, suppress_callback_exceptions, prevent_initial_callbacks, eager_loading, meta_tags, index_string, assets_external_path, include_assets_files, show_undo_redo, compress, update_title) in Dash at C:\Users\<User>\.julia\packages\Dash\Weukk\src\app\dashapp.jl:291
```

where I noticed a arg `assets_folder`. Putting in the absolute path seems to work so the full code looks something like this

```
using Dash
app = dash(assets_folder="/absolute/path/to/assets")
```